# fetching root folder structure recursively php

Tags: php, json

am new to php and json, i want to create a server side script that with a given path it gets folder structure in a given folder and shows the sub-folders and files recursively then returns  json,so how can i had the functionality of fetch folder structure recursively

like this

```
root
   |__subfolder
   |          |_mp3 
   |          |_png
   |__subfolder2
              |_mp3
              |_mp3
```

whats the best way of doing this

here is what have done so far

```
  <?php
$files = array();

$dir = opendir('/opt/');
while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
 if ($file == '.' || $file == '..')
 {
    continue;
 }

 $files[] = $file;
}

echo json_encode($files);
?>
```

Comment: Too much code, too little effort gone into actually solving your issue. Your question is unclear, is there an actual issue with this code or do you just want someone to add a function to it?? Please make sure you give the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) a read

Comment: @IsThisJavascript thank you for your response , i have edited my question please review it.

Comment: Ok that's much better. I'm not sure if I have an actual solution as I finish work shortly. May I suggest using the [RecursiveDirectoryIterator class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)